# jquery select / remove 'li' elements . limit amount and output URLs to input-box

Tags: jquery

I'm looking for some advise because having a hard time here with jQuery and my programming skills are close to 0

What i already have:

1. I have a list of images  from which i can chose one image/element with (+) button attached to each element
2. on button click selected image is removed from the image list and added to a new list in another div , button changes to (-) , select image URL is added to input-box field
3. click on (-) button remove selected image and add it to original div with all other images , button changes to (+) again and input field is cleared.

What i would like to modify to achieve following :

- be able to  select multiple images

I found that changing this line :

```
  $(this).closest('ul').append(UL_preview.children());
```

to

```
  $(this).closest('li').append(UL_preview.children());
```

let me select multiple element and move them to "selected images list/div"
altho  not sure if thats right way ??

- set the amount (limit) of images to select / selected li elements
  for example  2, 9

I found this `$("ol li:contains('Content'):lt(5)").show();`  but dont know how to use it in my code

- append input-box field with URLs  links to  all selected images  one
  after another (normally append replaces the input-box  value field
  with current URL)

I will really appreciate every bit of clarifications as its taking me days to figure it out.

here is the script with descriptions.

```
    <script>
    (function($){
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
            var optionId = <?php echo $_option->getId() ?>;


//on "+" button click select li element (image) and add it to selection ul

            $('#ind_option').on('click', 'button.select', function(){
                var imgEl = $(this).siblings('.image');

// insert url of image as a value in input-box 

                $("#options_" + optionId + "_myimage").val(imgEl.parent().data('image'));     


                var UL_preview = $("#img_preview_" + optionId);             
                if (UL_preview.children().length) {
                    $(this).closest('ul').append(UL_preview.children());
                }

                UL_preview.html(imgEl.closest('li'));

                //change button  from "+" to "-"
                reloadButtonClass();     

              });

//on "-" button click remove li element (image) from selection 

            $('#ind_option').on('click', 'button.unselect', function(){
                var imgEl = $(this).siblings('.image');

// remove url of the image from input-box field //
                $("#options_" + optionId + "_myimage").val('');     


                var liEl = imgEl.closest('li');
                $('#i-'+liEl.data('tab')+' ul.image_list').append(liEl);

//change button  from "-" to "+"

                reloadButtonClass();  
            });


//button's function change on elements 

            function reloadButtonClass() {
                $('.img_preview button.select').removeClass('select').addClass('unselect');
                $('.image_list button.unselect').removeClass('unselect').addClass('select');
            }
        });
    })(jQuery);
</script>
```

Comment: Can you put together a http://jsfiddle.net with some sample markup as well so we can look at what you have for HTML as well?

Comment: I put together 2 jsfiddle files ( btw amazing tool! didnt know it before)  1. this is how it works originally , alowing to select one image only --> [link](http://jsfiddle.net/utaf8/)  2.  slightly modified , so i can choose more images , but it still lacks desired functionality.  --> [link](http://jsfiddle.net/SWhDa/)    .   My apologize for the messy files  , but i changed all php code to html , so it will be easier to look after jquery only,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are there conditions where the data attribute for the image URL is going to be different than the actual image src? If not, you can clean up your markup and just use the image path of the image elements themselves by pulling the SRC attribute.

As far as solutions, I would set the selected box to be a UL like the image listing and move the image from one list to the other. Once you move the images to their respective lists, update your selected paths by simply getting all the paths of the selected images from the selected list, append them together, and plop them in your input. I changed it to a textarea and added a line break to clean it up for appearances.

Big block of code:

```
(function ($) {
    $(function () {
        var optionId = 4;

        $('#test_option').on('click', 'button.select', function () {
            var max = $('.numInputs option:selected').val();
            var pvw = $("#selected_preview_" + optionId);
            var count = pvw.children('li');
            if (max == 0 || (count < max)) {
                $(this).parent().appendTo(pvw);
                updatePaths();
            }
        }).on('click', 'button.unselect', function () {
            $('ul.test_image_list').append($(this).parent());
            updatePaths();
        });

        function updatePaths() {
            var pvw = $("#selected_preview_" + optionId);
            // textarea for paths
            var iPaths = $("#options_" + optionId + "_testimage");
            var pathStr = '';
            pvw.find('img').each(function () {
                pathStr += $(this).attr('src') + '/r/n';
            });
            iPaths.val(pvw);
            reloadButtonClass();
        }

        function reloadButtonClass() {
            $('.selected_preview button.select').removeClass('select').addClass('unselect');
            $('.test_image_list button.unselect').removeClass('unselect').addClass('select');
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Working, but still messy, Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/42PGF/3/ ;)

Comment: Thats one  big and brilliant block of code!. Thank you, I have learned a lot from it while adopting it to my original code. yes the data attribute is going to be different and I also had an issue, because in my code there are  tabbed ULs, so i was getting image back to all 4 tabs when removing it from pvw. I resolved it, o everything works as it should. You right, that a nice idea to copy the  selected UL list to my input box. will give it a try.   :)